# How to reverse batch normalization

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

In a regression network, I would like to use batch normalization on the objective `y` to obtain `y_norm` to fit. Because `y_norm` is well distributed.

In testing stage after training, I need to "undo" a batch normalization on the predicted `y_norm`. Is there any elegant way in tensorflow/keras in which I can construct an 
"undo" layer from the origin BN layer?

Comment: Well, you should have the original data right? You should have computed the `y_norm` from somewhere...

Comment: Do you mean in the training phase or in the testing phase? In the train phase, y_norm is just the output of a BN layers. In the testing phase, y_norm is the output of the prediction network (the BN layer is not included).

Answer (score 0):

I have found that [this](https://www.tensorflow.org/probability/api_docs/python/tfp/bijectors/BatchNormalization) layer has 2 methods: `inverse()` which performs the normalization and `forward()` which performs the de-normalization. So, in training you should use `inverse` and in inference the `forward` method.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! This is possibly an option. Yet, I am still curious if we can do it by the vanilla tensorflow api.

Comment: In addition, according to doc, "During training time, BatchNormalization.inverse and BatchNormalization.forward are not guaranteed to be inverses of each other because inverse(y) uses statistics of the current minibatch, while forward(x) uses running-average statistics accumulated from training." This is also a problem.

Comment: Well what you can do then is to go through the data and compute the mean and variance for the whole dataset and just fix it, again, for the whole dataset (both for normalization and de-normalization).

Comment: Yes, that would be the last option. It should also possible to extract gamma and beta from a keras layers and manually construct a de-normalization layer. But that is not elegant.